# How to get data from JavaScript tags in python?

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape from price data from an ecommerce website. I could do it using BS4 and getting HTML tags. code below.

```
import requests
from glob import glob
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep

HEADERS = ({'User-Agent':
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.5'})
url = "https://www.nykaa.com/lanvin-modern-princess-eau-de-parfum/p/338884?ptype=product&productId=338884&skuId=338884&categoryId=53&pps=4" ##JavaScript below refers to this link
#url = "https://www.nykaa.com/playboy-new-york-eau-de-toilette/p/196319?ptype=product&productId=196319&skuId=196319&categoryId=53&pps=17"
def nykaa_prices(url,HEADERS):
    try:
        page = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
    except(HTTPError, URLError, ValueError, EnvironmentError, RecursionError, ConnectionError) as ERROR:
        return None
    else:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, features="lxml")
        data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "m-content__product-des__details-wrap desktop-detail col-custom"})
        for dat in data:
            try:
                title = dat.find('h1', class_='product-title').text
                print('Name:',title)
            except:
                title = ''

            try:
                MRP = float(dat.find('span', {"class": "mrp-price"}).text.replace('₹', '').strip())
                print('MRP:',MRP)
            except:
                MRP = ''

            try:
                offerPrice = float(dat.find('span',{"class" :"post-card__content-price-offer"}).text.replace('₹', '').strip())
                print('OfferPrice:',offerPrice)
            except:
                offerPrice = ''

            try:
                discount = dat.find('div',{"class" :"discount-info"}).text.replace('off','').strip()
                print('Discount %:',discount)
            except:
                discount = ''

            try:
                rating = dat.find('div', {"class": "text-center rating-count-popup__rating-count"}).text.split()[0]
                print('Rating:',rating)
            except:
                rating = ''

            try:
                temp = dat.find('div',{"class" :"product-des__details-div scroll-to-target pull-left"})
                ratings = temp.text.split()[0]
                reviews = temp.text.split()[3]
                print("Ratings: {} \nReviews: {}".format(ratings,reviews))
            except:
                ratings = ''
                reviews = ''

    return

test = nykaa_prices(url,HEADERS)
```

I see that there is a block of `<script type="text/javascript">` (script I want to scrape,I put at the end) which contains everything I require for my project, including review comments and other details. I see it follows a json-ish format and if I can access that, I can get this project done. However, I am unable to do so, I have been hunting the web to find clue as to how to do this, but not getting anywhere.

In short, I want to access the `window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ =` in the JavaScript and read the tags `Key:Value` pairs contained in it. Since it contains a lot of pairs, I will decide later which all to read, but is there a way to do it?

JavaScript:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
   window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = {"appLevelReducer":{"userId":-1,"pageType":null,"productId":null,"productSku":null,"categoryId":null,"selectedStore":"","metaData":{"productPage":{"title":"Product_Name: Buy Product_Name Online at Best Price in India | Nykaa","description":"Product_Name Online: Buy Product_Name at best price from Nykaa. Check out Product_Name review. ✓COD ✓Free Shipping"},"brandPage":{"title":"Brand_Name - Buy Brand_Name Products Online at Best Price | Nykaa","description":"Brand_Name products: Buy Brand_Name products online at best price on Nykaa. Browse from a wide range of Brand_Name authentic products online at low price. ✓COD ✓Free shipping ✓Original Products"}},"storeConfig":{"status":false,"backToBeautyText":"Nykaa Main Store","exploreMoreStores":"https://images-static.nykaa.com/media/explore_stores_v5.png","stores":[]}},"deliveryOptionReducer":{"pinCode":null,"pinCodeMessages":null},"footerReducer":{"dummyData":"FOOTER: This is a dummy string defined in initial state of footerReducer.","footerLinks":[]},"headerReducer":{"categories":[]},"navigationReducer":{"categories":null,"brands":null,"desktopCategories":null,"desktopBrand":null,"beautyAdvice":null,"nykaaLogo":null,"popups":null,"style":null,"topStrip":""},"overlayReducer":{"isOverlayActive":false},"productReducer":{"product":{"description":"<p><b>SOURCED FROM PARCOS, THE OFFICIAL BRAND PARTNER</b></p><br><p>The new Lanvin fragrance explores a new vision of a woman: one who lives in mysterious ways, a rebellious adventurer.Free-spirited, she lives the life of a disarmingly modern princess, of one who breaks rules in general, and rules of romance in particular. Glamorous, untamed and fiercely sensual, she uses her own free will, playing with secrets and certainties. She has never been held prisoner of anything, nor of anyone. She creates her own destiny.</p><p><b>Fragrance Notes:</b><b>- Top Notes: </b>Pink Lady Apple, Red Currant<b>- Heart Notes: </b>Jasmine, Freesia<b>- Base Notes: </b>Vanilla Orchid, Musks</p><p><b>Fragrance Family:</b>Floral</p><br><p><b>About the Brand: </b><p>Created in 1889 by Jeanne Lanvin, the very first French Couture House is one of the leading references in the fashion industry. In 1924, Jeanne Lanvin created Lanvin Parfums at 4, Rond-Point des Champs-Elysees. The legendary Arpege fragrance was born three years later and was an immediate<br><br><p>Explore the entire range of <a href=/fragrance/women/perfumes-edt-edp/c/962 target=_blank> <u>Perfumes (EDT & EDP)</u></font></a> available on Nykaa. Shop more <a href=/luxe/brands/lanvin/c/5206?ptype=brand&id=5206 target=_blank> <u>Lanvin</u></font></a> products here.You can browse through the complete world of <a href=/luxe/brands/lanvin/c/5206?ptype=brand&id=5206&category_filter=962&sort=popularity target=_blank> <u> Lanvin Perfumes (EDT & EDP) </u></font></a>.</br>Alternatively, you can also find many more products from the <a href=/lanvin-modern-princess-eau-de-parfum/p/338884 target=_blank> <u>Lanvin Modern Princess Eau De Parfum</u></font></a> range.</p>","bulkbuyer_max_allowed_qty":null,"product_id":"338884","fbn":false,"price":3870,"show_wishlist_button":false,"d_sku":null,"manufacturer_ids":null,"quantity":10,"mrp_freeze":false,"star_rating_count":9,"max_allowed_qty":null,"type":"configurable","meta_title":"Buy Lanvin Modern Princess Eau De Parfum at Nykaa.com","meta_keywords":"Lanvin Modern Princess Eau De Parfum, Nykaa Luxe, Fragrance, Women","mrp":4300,"is_kit_combo":false,"brand_ids":"5206","button_text":"ADD TO BAG","is_luxe":true,"offer_count":[],"explore_more":[{"brand":{"url":"/luxe/brands/lanvin/c/5206?ptype=brand&id=5206&intcmp=pdp,explore_more,brand,Lanvin Modern Princess Eau De Parfum","message":"See more products from Lanvin","id":"5206"},"category":{"message":"See more Perfumes (EDT & EDP) products","id":"962","url":"/fragrance/women/perfumes-edt-edp/c/962?ptype=lst&id=962&intcmp=pdp,explore_more,category,Lanvin Modern Princess Eau De Parfum"},"brand_plus_cat":{"brand_id":"5206","category_id":"962","message":"See more Perfumes (EDT & EDP) products from Lanvin","url":"/luxe/brands/lanvin/c/5206?ptype=brand&id=5206&category_filter=962&sort=popularity&intcmp=pdp,explore_more,brand_and_category,Lanvin Modern Princess Eau De Parfum"},"filters":{"id":"962","type":"price","filter_value":"2000-3999","url":"/fragrance/women/perfumes-edt-edp/c/962?ptype=lst&id=962?price=2000-3999&sort=popularity&intcmp=pdp,explore_more,price_and_category,Lanvin Modern Princess Eau De Parfum","message":"See more Perfumes (EDT & EDP) products in this price range"}}],"pack_size":"","seller_rating":0,"highlights":"","pro_flag":0,"category_ids":"53,54,194,714,962,2880,2907,3126,3383,3841,3892,3894,5101,5206,5243,5245,5246,7648,7651,8653,8657,8742,8752,9215,9893,10396,10459,10469,11723,11783,11784,11790,12165,12166,12170,12932,13107,13687,14316,15259,15864,15865","eretailer":null,"bucket_discount_percent":null,"can_try":false,"media":[{"type":"image","url":"https://images-static.nykaa.com/media/catalog/product/tr:h-800,w-800,cm-pad_resize/3/3/3386460077217_2.jpg"},{"type":"image","url":"https://images-static.nykaa.com/media/catalog/product/tr:h-800,w-800,cm-pad_resize/3/3/3386460077217_1_1.jpg"},{"type":"image","url":"https://images-static.nykaa.com/media/catalog/product/tr:h-800,w-800,cm-pad_resize/c/e/certificate_nykaa_lanvin_1_6.jpg"}],"is_free_sample":0,"star_rating":4.6,"brand_name":["Lanvin"],"shipping_quote":null,"product_ingredients":"","can_try_type":"","meta_description":"Buy Lanvin Modern Princess Eau De Parfum Online From Nykaa.com at Best Price","qna_count":0,"tags":[],"seller_name":"Nykaa E retail private limited","in_stock":true,"variant_id":null,"variants":null,"parent_id":"338884","title":"Lanvin Modern Princess Eau De Parfum","category_levels":{"53":"0","54":"1","194":"0","962":"2","2880":"1","2907":"2","5101":"1","5243":"2","5245":"2","11723":"0","11783":"1","11784":"2","11790":"2"},"is_service":false,"backorders":false,"featured_in_titles":null,"sku":"LANV_LMPEDP","featured_in_urls":null,"vendor_sku":"","disabled":null,"catalog_tag":["luxe","nykaa","ultra_lux","store_essential","nykaaRetail"],"variant_type":"size","psku":"LANV_LMPEDP","expdt":"","is_saleable":true,"can_subscribe":false,"add_to_cart_url":"","star_rating_percentage":92,"slug":"lanvin-modern-princess-eau-de-parfum/p/338884","discount":10,"how_to_use":"<p>Spritz onto pulse points.</p>","review_splitup":{"0":{"count":"0","per":0,"star":1},"1":{"count":"0","per":0,"star":2},"2":{"count":"0","per":0,"star":3},"3":{"count":"4","per":44.44444444444444,"star":4},"4":{"count":"5","per":55.55555555555556,"star":5},"aggregated":4.6,"total_count":9},"review_count":"6","sizeData":{"enabled":false},"top_reviews":[{"title":"Feel like a princess","createdOn":"2020-11-29 19:32:28","description":"One of the classic Lanvin scents. To some extent all sweet Lanvin perfumes smell similar and this is no exception... Except this one is especially fruity and sweet! It does smell expensive and also girls in early to mid twenties, but I think any woman can pull this off. The top notes, heart notes and last notes are exactly as described. If you wanna feel like a princess, go for it. It will make you feel like you're wearing a soft pink organza dress with a sparkling tiara anywhere...\r\nThe picture is my hand holding the 60ml bottle. It's classy and cute, reminds you of a princess' dress. The liquid color is pale pink. Overall a beautiful perfume.","likeCount":"2","name":"Yumi Christina","id":"15884878","variantId":338883,"isLikedByUser":false,"isBuyer":true,"images":["https://images-static.nykaa.com/prod-review/1606679021424_688a0709-8223-4831-9bf5-e98eaa1313b6_1.jpg"],"profilePic":"https://images-static.nykaa.com/prod-review/default_profile_image.svg","createdOnText":"29/11/2020","rating":5},{"title":"Eau de parfum","createdOn":"2020-06-05 11:36:16","description":"It is very sensual kind of a fragrance , it stays long and packaging is so good","likeCount":"0","name":"priyal sharma","id":"13390905","variantId":338883,"isLikedByUser":false,"isBuyer":false,"images":[],"profilePic":"https://images-static.nykaa.com/prod-review/default_profile_image.svg","createdOnText":"05/06/2020","rating":5},{"title":"One of my favourtie fragrances","createdOn":"2020-03-15 17:40:49","description":"It has a perfect blend of sensual and fresh fragrance combination. Simply amazing one","likeCount":"0","name":"Ishu Singh","id":"12949471","variantId":338883,"isLikedByUser":false,"isBuyer":false,"images":[],"profilePic":"https://images-static.nykaa.com/prod-review/default_profile_image.svg","createdOnText":"15/03/2020","rating":4},{"title":"Smells so good","createdOn":"2020-01-25 10:28:40","description":"Best packaging, long-lasting and nice fragrance.","likeCount":"0","name":"aanchal raj","id":"12332489","variantId":338883,"isLikedByUser":false,"isBuyer":false,"images":[],"profilePic":"https://images-static.nykaa.com/prod-review/default_profile_image.svg","createdOnText":"25/01/2020","rating":5},{"title":"Best ever.","createdOn":"2019-07-29 10:27:54","description":"I love how good it makes me feel. My absolute favorite.","likeCount":"0","name":"Shraddha Verma","id":"6192251","variantId":338883,"isLikedByUser":false,"isBuyer":false,"images":[],"profilePic":"https://images-static.nykaa.com/prod-review/default_profile_image.svg","createdOnText":"29/07/2019","rating":5}],"offers":[],"options":[
```

There is a lot more to this script, I can send a file if required, else inspecting this [URL](https://www.nykaa.com/lanvin-modern-princess-eau-de-parfum/p/338884?ptype=product&productId=338884&skuId=338884&categoryId=53&pps=4) will show the script.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using selenium for scraping, this will work fine:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

option = Options()
option.add_argument('--headless')
url = 'https://www.nykaa.com/lanvin-modern-princess-eau-de-parfum/p/338884?ptype=product&productId=338884&skuId=338884&categoryId=53&pps=4'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)
driver.get(url)
bs = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
x = bs.find_all('script', {'type': 'text/javascript'})
driver.quit()
for item in x:
    p = item.contents
    f = "".join(p)
    if "window.__PRELOADED_STATE__" in f:
        print(p[0].split("\n")[0])
```

Comment: Cool. I will try the selenium approach. An issue I forsee is that `"window.__PRELOADED_State__" = {...}` is followed by `"window.someothertext = {}"`. I need only the tags with Preloaded state.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I could modify the code and get it working based on your input.

Comment: @Abhishek Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Might searching the line which containing windows.**PRELOADED_STATE** = ...... json string....

Split this line by = or removing the first part of of the equal.

Finally, parsing the final string: json.loads(json string)

Comment: I tried doing this. Cant use `=` as it splits the content inside the `{}` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I made the following the code based on @Cute Panda's inputs.

````
    try:
        page = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
    except(HTTPError, URLError, ValueError, EnvironmentError, RecursionError, ConnectionError) as ERROR:
        return None
    else:
        bs = BeautifulSoup(page.content, features="lxml")
        x = bs.find_all('script', {'type': 'text/javascript'})
        # if len(x) == 0:
        #     return None
        for item in x:
            p = item.contents
            f = "".join(p)
            if "window.__PRELOADED_STATE__" in f:
                #print(p[0].split("\n")[0])
                text = p[0].split("\n")[0]
                break
        else:
            return None

        data_json = json.loads(text.replace("window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ",""))
        _l_common = ["title","star_rating_count","star_rating"]
        _l_option = ["brand_name", "parent_id", "id", "pack_size", "mrp", "discount", "price", "inStock"]
        _l_noOption = ["brand_name", "parent_id", "product_id", "pack_size", "mrp", "discount", "price", "in_stock"]
        _output = []
        _out_common = [data_json['productReducer']['product'][_key] for _key in _l_common]
        if "options" in data_json['productReducer']['product'].keys():
            for _item in range(len(data_json['productReducer']['product']['options'])):
                _val = [data_json['productReducer']['product']['options'][_item][_key] for _key in _l_option]
                _val.extend(_out_common)
                _output.append(flatten_list(_val))
        else:
            _val = [data_json['productReducer']['product'][_key] for _key in _l_noOption]
            _val.extend(_out_common)
            _output.append(flatten_list(_val))
    return _output```

Now there is a lot of information I am not picking up. I don't really know how to store all that information. Excel ofcourse won't work. I was thinking a database to keep all the information from various tags from the code. Run it once and store a lot of static info (all except price and discount info is relevant in this case), but I really don't know where to start and how to even do it.
And I want to experiment with cloud storage. 
Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks Cute Panda once again!
````